# How does cloudlfare (or other CDN) detect direct IP address requests?

Tags: http, https, dns, cloudflare

So I did a DNS lookup of a website hosted through cloudflare.

I pasted the IP address in my address bar and got a page saying:

*Error 1003 Ray ID: 729ca4f4aff82e38 • 2022-07-12 20:49:14 UTC
Direct IP access not allowed*

If my browser is doing the same thing i.e. fetching the ip using the url then sending a HTTPS req to the same IP, but when I do it manually I am getting this error -  how can cloudflare detect that its a direct IP access attempt?

Comment: The browser adds a `host` header to the request https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/host

Comment: and that doesnt get added when i paste the url directly in the address bar?

Comment: When you paste a URL with a DNS name in the address bar the browser will include the `host` header in the request. When you paste a URL with an IP address in the address bar, the browser doesn't know the DNS name, so it will just use the IP address in the `host` header, or not send the `host` header at all. Thus the CDN simply has to look at the `host` header to see if you are accessing the server via DNS name or IP address.

Answer (score 1):

> how can cloudflare detect that its a direct IP access attempt?

Just based on what you (your browser) are sending!

An URL is of the form `http://hostname/path` considering that hostname can be an IP address.

When you put that in your browser, the browser will split the parts and do an HTTP query.

The HTTP protocol defines an HTTP message to be headers plus an optional body. Among headers, one is called `host` and the value is exactly what was in URL.

Said differently, between `http://www.example.com/` and `http://192.0.2.42/` (if [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) was resolving to that IP address):

- at the TCP/IP level nothing changes: in both cases, through OS, the browser connects at IP address `192.0.2.42` (because the `www.example.com` from first URL will be resolved to its IP address)
- when it starts the HTTP exchange, the message sent by the client will then have as header either `host: www.example.com` in the first case or `host: 192.0.2.42` in the second case
- the webserver sees obviously all headers sent by client, including this `host` one and hence can do whatever it wants with it, and most importantly select which website was requested if multiple websites resolves to the same IP address (if you understand the text above, you now see why the `host` header is necessary). If URLs are `https://` and not just `http://` there is a subtetly because there is another layer between the TCP/IP connection and the HTTP application protocol, which is TLS, and the equivalent of the `host` header is sent also at the TLS level, through what is called the SNI extension, so that the server can also decide which server certificate it needs to send back to the client, before even the first byte of the HTTP exchange is done.